# How to handle popup window using selenium RC with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

I trying to automate eCommerce website & i have a problem how to handle pop-up window.Please take a look on the scenario.

1. Go to http://www.angara.com/p/pear-tanzanite-and-diamond-v-bale-pendant-sp0169t.html
2. On the product page click on "Add to cart" button (this will add a product to cart and display a pop-up)
3. On the pop-up window i want to click on checkout button (This will close the pop-up)

I have stuck on point no 3 and error is come up element not found.

Here is something i have written.

@Test
public void angara_Home_product(){

```
 selenium.click("xpath=//span[contains(text(),'Tanzanite Pendant')]");
 selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
 assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Pear Tanzanite and Diamond V-Bale Pendant"));
 selenium.click("xpath=//img[@class='imgsize']/@src[1]");
 selenium.click("css=#option-list-tab272 > span");
 selenium.click("xpath=//div[@id='option-container3341']/div/div/span");
 selenium.click("css=#option-list-tab332 > span");
 selenium.click("xpath=//span[contains(text(),'14K Yellow Gold')]");
 selenium.click("//input[@name='addToCartSubmit' and @value='ADD TO CART']");

      //Some code should be there which might handle the pop-up window.

 selenium.click("xpath=//*[@id='cart-top-checkout-button']");
 selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
 assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Express Checkout"));
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:
I think there should be wait command after step 2 and I have edited the xpath for step 3.

```
selenium.click("xpath=//span[contains(text(),'Tanzanite Pendant')]");
 selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
 assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Pear Tanzanite and Diamond V-Bale Pendant"));
 selenium.click("xpath=//img[@class='imgsize']/@src[1]");
 selenium.click("css=#option-list-tab272 > span");
 selenium.click("xpath=//div[@id='option-container3341']/div/div/span");
 selenium.click("css=#option-list-tab332 > span");
 selenium.click("xpath=//span[contains(text(),'14K Yellow Gold')]");
 selenium.click("//input[@name='addToCartSubmit' and @value='ADD TO CART']");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("10000");

      //Some code should be there which might handle the pop-up window.

 selenium.click("xpath=//form[@id='updatepost_form']//*[@id='cart-top-checkout-button']");
 selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
 assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Express Checkout"));
```

Comment: Timed out after 10000ms error is come up when i use your code.

Comment: can you use Thread.sleep(10000); instead of selenium.waitForPageToLoad("10000"); and give it try.

Comment: Can you please let me know what error you are getting now

Comment: Sumit, I have used the below code and now it is working. try {
  Thread.sleep(10000);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }